# If I wanted to have Line-In and Microphone at the same time, how would I achieve this?

Tags: microphone

During livestreams, I want to be able to play games via my PSP, and still be able to hear it. At the same time, I'd like to be able to speak through microphone.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What Operating System?  Do you have the PSP connected to your Line In, and your Microphone plugged into the Mic input currently?  Have you opened your Recording mixer, and enabled both?  What are the configurations you have tried, and what were the results?